# How to get StackPanel's content height?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to bind my window's height to the StackPanel's height. What is the easiest way to get  the StackPanel's content height?

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to use binding instead of [Window.SizeToContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx)?

Comment: @Joe White I split window for left and right side. In left side I have stackpanel with rather short content and in right side I have stackpanel with too big content's height. So, I want the window not to be very long, but show all the left's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `MyStackPanel.ActualHeight` since a `StackPanel's` height is based off of the size of it's contents.

**Edit**

You'll also want to set the `VerticalAlignment` of your `StackPanel` to something other than `Stretch` if it is inside another panel which stretches it's children by default, such as a `Grid` or a `DockPanel`.

Comment: You would probably also need to set the StackPanel's VerticalAlignment to something other than Stretch. Otherwise its ActualHeight will be set by its parent, not its content.